# How can I use the compile time constant __LINE__ in a string?

Tags: c++, testing, c-preprocessor

I can use `__LINE__` as a method parameter just fine, but I would like an easy way to use it in a function that uses strings.

For instance say I have this:

```
11    string myTest()
12    {
13     if(!testCondition)
14       return logError("testcondition failed");
15    }
```

And I want the result of the function to be:

> "myTest line 14: testcondition failed"

How can I write logError? Does it have to be some monstrosity of a macro?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Why do you even need it as a string?  What's wrong with an integer?  Here are two ways you could write `logError()`:

```
#define logError(str) fprintf(stderr, "%s line %d: %s\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, str)

// Or, forward to a more powerful function
#define logError(str) logError2(__FILE__, __LINE__, str)
void logError2(const char *file, int line, const char *str);
```

If you really need the line as a string, you can use the stringizing operator `#`, but because of the way macros work, you'll need to wrap it in two macros:

```
#define STRINGIZE(x) STRINGIZE2(x)
#define STRINGIZE2(x) #x
#define LINE_STRING STRINGIZE(__LINE__)
```

And now `LINE_STRING` is a macro that will expand to a string containing the current line number wherever it is expanded.  If you only had one level of macros (i.e. if you had `#define STRINGIZE(x) #x`), then you would get the literal string `"__LINE__"` every time you expanded it, which is not what you want.

Comment: While, this is an old thread, a reason you would want it as a string as instances where you can't use fprintf(). One such place is in a signal handler as fprintf() is not safe for use in signal handlers while write() is.

Answer (score 40):

There's no reason to do any run-time work for this:

```
#include <iostream>

// two macros ensures any macro passed will
// be expanded before being stringified
#define STRINGIZE_DETAIL(x) #x
#define STRINGIZE(x) STRINGIZE_DETAIL(x)

// test
void print(const char* pStr)
{
    std::cout << pStr << std::endl;
}

int main(void)
{
    // adjacent strings are concatenated
    print("This is on line #" STRINGIZE(__LINE__) ".");
}
```

---

Or:

```
#define STOP_HAMMER_TIME(x) #x
#define STRINGIFICATE(x) STOP_HAMMER_TIME(x)
```

If you're a cool person like James.

Comment: Or, if you despise the word `STRINGIZE`, you can use `STRINGIFICATE` and enjoy odd stares from your coworkers.

Comment: I use word "stringify" for that :)

Answer (score 12):

His goal is to create a macro (named **logError**) that will automatically include the symbols necessary and do the string concatenation within the preprocessor, only using string literals.

So, combining the basically-correct answers answers thus far, let's write the macro:

```
#define STRINGIZE_DETAIL(x) #x
#define STRINGIZE(x) STRINGIZE_DETAIL(x)
#define logError(msg) (__FILE__ " line " STRINGIZE(__LINE__) ": " msg)
```

You can then use this macro anywhere to create a generic error message code in string literal format at compile time.

Note: You can also use `__FUNCTION__` (or an equivalent, it varies by compiler) instead of `__FILE__`, if you prefer, to keep track of the function name instead of the file name.

Answer (score 3):

The usual options for formatting a number into a string apply:  Boost lexical_cast, ostringstream, sprintf or snprintf, etc.

Here is one of my favorite links on the topic: http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill19.htm

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's ugly. You need a combination of macros. Converting an integer to a string is a two-step process - here's Boost's implementation:

```
#define BOOST_STRINGIZE(X) BOOST_DO_STRINGIZE(X)
#define BOOST_DO_STRINGIZE(X) #X
```

Now you can generate a string:

```
logError(__FILE__ BOOST_STRINGIZE(__LINE__) "testcondition failed");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
std::string logError(const char* file, int line, const char* msg)
{
   std::ostringstream os;
   os << file << ' ' << line << ':' << msg;
   return os.str();
}
```

Usage:

```
return logError(__FILE__, __LINE__, "my error message");
```

You could then make a macro for this if you were so inclined:

```
#define LOG_ERROR(x) logError(__FILE__, __LINE__, (x))
```

And then the usage would be:

```
return LOG_ERROR("my error message");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sprintf(newStringBuffer, "myTest line %d: testcondition failed\n", __LINE__);
```

should do it c style.  I know that there are ways and ways of doing this with the C++ string libraries.

You could also use strcat() or strncat or any other number of C libs to do this.

```
cout <<"String" + __LINE__ + " another string"
```

will work as well.

Comment: The aim isn't to output it to screen but to return a string with the write data in.

Comment: Why not just `cout << "String" << __LINE__ << "Another string";`? No need for casting or concatenating.

Comment: I know there are C++ string methods that overload operator+() to do string cats, I jsut wasn't sure of the syntax.  I've always done these C style...

Comment: @billy... no? I don't mention cout or console anywhere. Edit it if you want.

Comment: @John: You do mention "output", and it looks like you're talking about the output of the program itself.

Comment: It's still going through a function. That's the main feature. Using cout makes this a non-question :) But I clarified now anyhow.

Comment: Why the negative vote?  Awe, someone went neg crazy, no big deal then :)

Comment: Because that's how SO works. If I like your answer I vote it up. If it's OK but not as detailed as a great answer, no vote. If it doesn't answer the question or is a bad asnwer, I vote it down. Isn't that the point, that each person votes to try and get the answers ordered based on their preference.

Answer (score -3):

Try this?

```
string myTest(const int lineno)
{
  if(!testCondition)
    return logError ("testcondition failed", lineno);
}

void logError (string msg, const int lineno)
{
  clog << "line " << lineno << ": " << msg << endl;
}
```

Comment: Your logError doesn't return a string.