# C++ concatenation in macro

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, stringification

I have the following set of macros (which I got from the first answer for [How can I use the compile time constant __LINE__ in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670816/how-can-i-use-the-compile-time-constant-line-in-a-string)) defined in an attempt to have a macro 'LOCATION_PREFIX' that I can use to "capture" the location of a line of code (will be passed to other functions that will perform logging).

```
#define STRINGIZE(f,l) STRINGIZE2(f) "(" STRINGIZE2(l)"):"
#define STRINGIZE2(x) #x
#define LOCATION_PREFIX STRINGIZE(__FILE__, __LINE__)

int main(){

printf("%s here\n", LOCATION_PREFIX);
printf("%s over here\n", LOCATION_PREFIX);

return 1;
}
```

Output:

> "t.cpp"(8): here
>       "t.cpp"(9): over here

I want the output to be:

> t.cpp(8): here
>       t.cpp(9): over here

Any help is greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the first `STRINGIZE2` invocation, as the file name is already a quoted string:

```
#define STRINGIZE(f,l) f "(" STRINGIZE2(l) "):"
#define STRINGIZE2(x) #x
#define LOCATION_PREFIX STRINGIZE(__FILE__, __LINE__)

int main(){
  printf("%s here\n", LOCATION_PREFIX);
  printf("%s over here\n", LOCATION_PREFIX);

  return 1;
}
```

Comment: Cheers ! Works perfectly, thank you very much for the quick response... will accept the answer as soon as I can.

Comment: Notice, that you then can also drop the `f` argument of `STRINGIZE` and directly put `__FILE__` in there. I didn't do it so there's a clear relation to your code, though.

Comment: made the change to remove the passing of __FILE__, STRINGIZE now only takes (l).